# How do I properly utilize an external an external dependency like bcrypt in a Nuxt 3 app?

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, vite, bcrypt

Currently, in my Nuxt 3 app, I have a registration form that collects a username, email, and password. Before sending the password in a POST request, I would like to hash the password. My first instinct was to use [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)-- however, upon installing and importing inside my `login.vue` file, I received a plethora of errors. In this instance the culprit is the bcrypt dependency `mock-aws-s3`, but I also get the same error for dependencies `nock` and `aws-sdk`.

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "mock-aws-s3"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:43:28:
      43 │     const AWSMock = require('mock-aws-s3');
```

It looks like there are some bundling issues with the package, and Nuxt says I can potentially resolve the issue by marking the package as external (which I've tried with no success). Furthermore, I additionally get the error:

```
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".html" files: node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js:86:21:
      86 │       return require('./' + command)(self, argvx, callback);
         ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This I don't understand, and was wondering if anyone here would know the cause of this error. Largely, I'm wondering if I'm doing this completely wrong, or if there is simply no way to use bcrypt in a .vue file.

To summarize, I expected to be able to install the package `bcrypt` via npm, import it in my `login.vue` file, and be able to use the package's functions as per usual, but I encountered many errors upon running my app.